# One quick question, I have multiple payloads that should iterate thru one by one. How do pass them in one function

Tags: python, post, request

```
url = http://url

input = os.environ.get("input")

payload1_res_input = ""
payload2_res_input = ""

def invoke_request():

    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    try:
        req=requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload.....)
        if req.status_code == 200:
            print(req.json())
            response = req.json()
            if payload1:
                payload1_res_input = response['data']['xyz']['list'][0]['payload1res']
            elif payload2:
                payload2_res_input = response['data']['abc']['list'][0]['payload2res']
        else:
            print("\n Caught exception & Status code", req.status_code, req.close())
    except Exception as e:
        print('Caught Exception', e)
        
payload1 = json.dumps({
        "query": "query{\r\n    xyz(input:\"%s\") {\r\n    list{  \r\payload1res}\r\n}}"%(input),
        "variables": {} 
})
payload2 = json.dumps({
        "query": "query{\r\n    abc(payload1res:\"%s\", offset: 1, pagesize: 10){\r\n    list{payload2res   }metadata{\r\n\t   pageNumber\r\n        limit\r\n        totalPages\r\n totalRecords\r\n\t}\r\n}}"%(payload1res),
        "variables": {}
})
payload3 = json.dumps({
        "query": "mutation{\r\n\r\n    tgj(idInput: {payload1res: \"%s\",\r\n    payload2res: \"%s\", \r\n    hgshjfg:\"jsjfh\" })\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n}"%(payload1res,payload2res),
        "variables": {}}
})

for payload in (payload1, payload2, payload3)
invoke_request(payload)
```

Above is the block of code. getting exception right after payload1
execution saying caught exception 'data'. I should iterate the payload one by one to retrieve the response fields to use them in next request. I hope that gives some info.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean.  Do you mean you need to make N different requests?  That requires a loop, like `response = [requests.post(url, data=p...) for p in (payload1,pyload2,...)]`.

Comment: Tried above, payload1 is going thru but from payload2 is going for exception.

Comment: Which exception?  There could be a thousand things wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the alignments, I added my current code above, for the 1st payload it is going thru, then it caught exception saying 'data'

Comment: 'data' is not an exception, and what you're showing is not valid Python code.  Get rid of the `try`/`except` until you have this all debugged.